# List<T> is not working

Tags: c#, list, generics

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;    



public string[] UpdateCGPA()
            {
                List<string> list = new List<string>();

                conn.Open();
                string STDid = "SELECT Student_ID from Students";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(STDid, conn);
                MySqlDataReader myReader;
                myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    list.Add(Convert.ToString(myReader.GetString(0)));

                }
                string[] array = list.ToArray();

                return array;
            }
```

VS2008 giving error at this line:
List list = new List();

error says
The type or namespace name 'List' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `ArrayList` is **not** the same thing as `List<T>` (generic list).

Answer (score 5):

add System.Collections.Generic name space

Answer (score 2):

Don't you need to import this package in the class?

**using System.Collections.Generic;**

Answer (score 2):

Move cursor on to the list in  `List<string> list = new List<string>();`and press `CTRL + .` to see the required namespace or you can add one your self on top of the page as follows

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```